# November 5 and 6 time difference (php)

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

I was writing a simple code with some date calculations.  I ran into an interesting issue; the following code is simply calculating how many hours are there between two dates, and the result should read 24 hours.  For different dates I plugged in I come up with 24, but these two dates is 25.  Does anyone know why?  I have a program that I jump days, and group by stuff in sql by date, and it's a bit annoying that `$date+24*60*60;` still falls in the same date at `23:00` hours.

```
<?php

$first = mktime(0, 0, 0,11, 5, 2017);

$second = mktime(0, 0, 0,11, 6, 2017); 

$delta = ($second - $first)/60/60;


echo $delta."<BR>";

?>
```

Comment: works for me https://3v4l.org/B69Kd

Comment: The reason is called daylight saving time... It depends on your timezone. With those dates and this result of 25hours, it looks like one of the North America timezones...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daylight savings time ended in the USA on the 5th. Is that where your timezone is set up?

Comment: Thank you for this tip.  That's it. I've added date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Istanbul'); to my code and it's now showing 24h.  Now I have to research how to avoid the daylight savings time.